# set html button state based on query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page with '`favourite`' button that when clicked runs an Ajax post and updates my db table '`favourite`' accordingly **user** and **book** details.

The current process is as follows,

- click button **once** > add book to favourite table > refresh page > display success `div`
- click button **again** > delete book from favourite table > refresh page > display success `div`

What I would like to do now is on page load, check if the user has already added the book as a favourite, if so, set the class of this button to btn-success (green).

How do I achieve this? Do I need to give the button an attribute on page load and check this on page load?

I am quite new to php and js so any advice is appreciated. I have included my code for reference.

**ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$( "#fav" ).click(function(){    

book_id = $(fav).val(); // set the value of the button as the book_id

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '<?php echo URL; ?>books/checkFav',
         data: {book_id:book_id},
         success: function () { 
             window.location.reload(true);
            }//end success        
        });//end ajax   
    });
});
```

**checkFav php**

```
$bookid=$_REQUEST['book_id']; //get this from ajax
$userid=$_SESSION['user_id']; //get this from session

$sql = "SELECT * FROM favourite WHERE book_id = :book_id AND user_id = :user_id";

   ... //execute

if(empty($rows_found)) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO favourite (book_id, user_id) VALUES (:book_id, :user_id)";

... //execute

} else { 
$sql = "DELETE FROM favourite WHERE book_id = :book_id AND user_id = :user_id";

... //execute       
}
```

**html**

```
echo '<td>
<button id="fav" value="'.$book->id.'" type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button></td>';
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Yes, you need to track the favorites of each user and apply those, typically a class, when you load the page.

Comment: you can write a function (per example isFavorite() ) in php in your book model / class that checked if this book is marked as favorite from logged in user. in html you write this: 
`<button id="fav" value="'.$book->id.'" type="button" class="btn btn-default <?php echo ($book->isFavorite()) ? 'favorite' : '';?>"></button>`.
In your css you can create your .favorite class.

Comment: `.$book->id.` this is not correct way to write, you cant add it in html this way

Comment: I dont think its correct @johnny_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. make a php function that checks if it is already a favorite or not and returns true or false and based on that add a class to the button like this:

   $("#buttonId").addClass("btn-success");
2. if you already have this data when the page loads you can add a php code inline in the html like this:

   if($favorite){
       $class = "btn-success";
   }

and then in the html

```
<button id="fav" value="<?php echo $book->id; ?>" type="button" class="btn <?php echo ($book->isFavorite()) ? 'favorite' : '';?>"></button>
```

Comment: `"'.$book->id.'" ` IS THIS CORRECT ?...have you tried it  , is it working for u

Comment: I think you should use:
<?php echo $book->id; ?>
but just $book->id might work as well
no need for the dots because you're not connecting 2 strings

Comment: ok so you have to make an ajax call to a php function that looks similar to the php function that you have above. The function should return true if it's already a favorite, and false if it isn't. I believe that is the best practice to do it. for more info about ajax check this site: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/      it is very important to learn ajax that way not all your php code is inline.

Comment: in my code the php echo dumps what the function returns, you did it so that you will return true or false. when you run it does it add the class "true" to the button? if so just change the function to return the class name instead of true or false. understand? or you can make an ajax request to the php function when the page is ready and if the result you get is true then use javascript (or jquery) to add the "btn-success" class to the button.

Answer (score 2):

This is incorrect:

```
<button id="fav" value="'.$book->id.'" type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
```

You must specify that you want PHP code and you want to `echo` `$book->id`, like this:

```
<button id="fav" value="<?php echo $book->id; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
```

Also, let's suppose you have a PHP function `isFavorite`, then

```
<button id="fav" value="<?php echo $book->id; ?>" type="button" class="btn btn-default<?php echo ((isFavorite()) ? (" btn-success") : ("")); ?>"></button>
```

Comment: I too thought that :)

Comment: Not really. Try out my answer and make sure you implement isFavorite and implement it.

Comment: No, you need the echo here as well. Use the syntax from my answer. isFavorite should return true if it is a favorite and false otherwise.